# python import module for code in another py file

Tags: python, import

Hi I store user defined functions in a separte file `my_functions.py`. E.g.,

```
#my_functions.py
def some_func():
    sleep(1)
    print(1)
```

And the main code in another file `main.py`:

```
#main.py
from time import sleep
from my_functions import *

some_func()
```

When I run `main.py`, I have error that `sleep` is not define. It seems things imported from `my_functions.py` doesn't know about `from time import sleep`

Should I import time module in `my_funcions.py`?

I feel confused, cause I thought only `some_func` is imported, and if I write `from time import sleep` in `my_functions.py`, this sentence won't get executed...

And more general advice about how to store user defined functions is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you need to import the module(s) and/or entities needed by `my_functions.py` in that file.  And don't worry, even though you may import the same thing in multiple files, Python will keep track of it and will only load the file once (even though it may populate multiple namespaces from it).

Answer (score 1):

```
from time import sleep
#my_functions.py
def some_func():
    sleep(1)
    print(1)
```

You need to import the function in the file/module where you use it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should import the time module in my_functions.py.  hope this helps you understanding how import works:

> Import statements are executed in two steps: (1) find a module, and initialize it if necessary; **(2) define a name or names in the local namespace (of the scope where the import statement occurs).** The first form (without from) repeats these steps for each identifier in the list. The form with from performs step (1) once, and then performs step (2) repeatedly.
>   https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/import.html

Here is [a style guide from PEP008 about import](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)